# global name not error defined in python after declaration

Tags: python-3.x

I declared a global variable in python and still i'm facing error saying that variable is not defined. Can someone please please help me.

```
def _pick_server (self, key, inport):
global scount1
global scount2
global scount3
server1wt = 4
server2wt = 1
server3wt = 2
liveservers = sorted(self.live_servers.keys())
for i in liveservers:
    print(i)
if (scount1 < server1wt):
    scount1 += scount1
    print(scount1)
    print (liveservers[0])
    return liveservers[0]
elif (scount2 < server3wt):
    scount2 += scount2
    print (liveservers[1])
    return liveservers[1]
elif (scount3 < server3wt):
    scount3 += scount3
    print (liveservers[2])
    return liverservers[2]
else:
    scount1 = 1
    scount2 = 0
    scount3 = 0
    liveservers[0]
```

The error i'm getting is as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/mininet/pox/pox/lib/revent/revent.py", line 231, in 
raiseEventNoErrors
return self.raiseEvent(event, *args, **kw)
File "/home/mininet/pox/pox/lib/revent/revent.py", line 278, in raiseEvent
rv = event._invoke(handler, *args, **kw)
File "/home/mininet/pox/pox/lib/revent/revent.py", line 156, in _invoke
return handler(self, *args, **kw)
File "/home/mininet/pox/ext/ents_loadbalancer.py", line 307, in 
_handle_PacketIn
server = self._pick_server(key, inport)
File "/home/mininet/pox/ext/ents_loadbalancer.py", line 203, in _pick_server
if (scount1 < server1wt):
NameError: global name 'scount1' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

your using `scount1` before defining it

how can you test its value when it is unknown?

### Solution

`scount1 = 1`
before

`if (scount1 < server1wt)`

Comment: i dont want to assign any value to scount1 bcoz this script is used by many instances and as soon i assign value, everytime scount IF condition is executed, scount2 and scount3 is never executed. Can you please tell me a way to initialize a variable without assigning values to it, like scount1, scount2 and scount3.

Comment: @g.tomy you asking something that seems to me impossible. *You want to compare a value that is not known?*, **Here's a solution: test for smaller values first** if `server3wt` is the smallest then do `if (scount2 <server3wt)` first then look for the next smaller one from `server1wt` and `server3wt` and test for it. Do you understand me?

Comment: i got the solution i assigned values to those variables outside the class and its working fine now.

Comment: Good for you, yes those variable must be initialized before comparing them